# Pivot data by category with aggregation

Tags: sql, pivot

I have following structure:

```
Date,           Type,       Country,     Sales,     NumOfItems
2020-12-24,     Basic,      USA,         700,       5
2020-12-24,     Standard,   USA,         300,       3
2020-12-24,     Basic,      USA,         100,       1
2020-12-24,     Standard,   USA,         200,       6
```

how to pivot this data in order to get below structure:

```
Date,        Country,  Sales,  NumOfItems,  SalesBasic,  NumOfItemsBasic,  SalesStandard,  NumOfItemsBasic
2020-12-24,  USA,      1300,   15,          800,         6                 500             9
```

and group by Date and country?

thanks in advance for any advice and best regards!

Comment: Use conditional aggregation (with `CASE` expression), it works for all the RDBMSes

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate on CASE statements, for example:

```
SELECT Date, Country, SUM(Sales) AS Sales, SUM(NumOfItems),
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Basic' THEN Sales ELSE null END) AS SalesBasic,
       ...
 GROUP BY 
       Date, Country
```